# How can I configure RazorEngine to use VB as the language?

Tags: vb.net, razorengine

I'm trying to use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/) to render templates and my templates are in VB.NET.  The documentation is thin (or wrong) about how to specify what language the template parser should use, and I can't figure out how to configure it to use VB.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying `VB` as the language in the `razorEngine` -> `templateServices` config section?

```
<razorEngine>
    <templateServices>
        <add name="myCustomTemplateService" language="VB" />
    </templateServices>
<razorEngine>
```

From the original CodePlex site - [Using Configuration](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Configuration)

See the section called **Accessing configured template services**